# What loadFactor and initial size should be used while creating a HashMap if we need to store 100K Entry in it <String, Object>?

Tags: java, memory-management, collections, cpu-usage

I am using InsertedOrderHashMap to store 5K to 120K entries. I am using default constructor of HashMap which has default size 16 and load factor (0.75).

My question here is, how we can optimize this? I need to optimize my use case for CPU usage as well as memory usage. Should we increase the load factor to reduce the CPU utilization or some other way ?

Thanks a million for your help!

Regards,
Saurav

Comment: You should probably use a database instead.

Comment: No, we are not supposed to use DB. Thanks !

Comment: How does increasing the load factor reduce CPU utilization. Do you mean it will save time on reallocation? But then wouldnt resolving collisions be an issue as it is highly likely that you will have more collisions because you will reallocate only after a bigger percentage of the datastructure is full. The load factor of 0.75 is optimal. However if you know the number of elements you are going to store, creating a hashmap with that capacity will be optimal. What is most important is your hash algorithm and if that works fine, you wouldn't have to worry about others unless you notice a bottlene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increasing the load factor, increases the point at which the HashMap resizes.  This increases CPU once it has reached a stable size but saves some memory.

The size of a HashMap is always a power of 2 so you have two options.

- either increase your CPU to save some memory and use `128 * 1024` capacity and a load factor close to 1, or
- you make the capacity `256 * 1024` and the leave the default load factor.